Contextual menus broken in Firefox 128?
Yesterday I upgraded to Firefox 128 (not the snap version). My contextual menus are now unusable:

Runs off top and bottom of screen vertically
Filled with unlabeled 'options' (e.g., checkboxes, etc.)
Incoherent menu options are presented (e.g., transport controls a la play, stop, mute, etc. when I hover over a hyperlink to a static webpage, etc.).
Unresponsive interface (e.g., selecting "Copy Link" does not actually copy the link to the clipboard).

I get this with all extensions disabled. I get this when running in safe mode/troubleshooting mode. I am using Firefox with GNOME/X-Org on Ubuntu 22.04.4.
No idea how to troubleshoot, or how to remedy. I cannot provide a screenshot, as opening the screenshot utility hides the contextual menu.

Does what you are clicking on change the menu in an observable way? I am less familiar with Ubuntu's screencap functions, but can you press PrtScn and capture the screen that way without opening a utility? Also, please add your OS as a tag to the question. Does uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox change the behavior any?

@music2myear, for Ubuntu, standard keyboard shortcut for full screen capture is Shift + Print, though the shortcuts can be edited.

If only you could go back to FF 127 to verify what you've reported then possibly open a bug.  I had an incident some years back where firefox suddenly made a color mess of many images on certain websites.  To cut down, and all but eliminate such problems in the future I recommend two actions.  1) participate in the Firefox Nightly efforts where you can test your Firefox use using a future firefox.  I'm writing this using Firefox 130, due to become 'production' 9/3/24.

The second recommendation is to manually install firefox production on your system - in addition to the Firefox nightly.  I pick up a new production version every other month from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-esr.  I always set aside the last production version so that should something unacceptable hit the production release, I can regress until it is fixed.


Are you using the Snap version, or the packages from Mozilla as PPA?

In either case, start by running Firefox in Troubleshooting Mode (Safe Mode).

If that does not resolve the issue, then consider refreshing Firefox, i.e., reinstall it automatically. Though Mozilla states, "The refresh feature creates a new profile folder and saves your important data," you likely will lose all extensions and their settings, so make note of current add-ons before refreshing. You might want to make your own copy of your Firefox profile, just in case...

Finally, you might try getting the latest version from an alternate source, i.e., uninstall Snap version and install from Mozilla PPA, or vice versa.


BTW, there are simple keyboard shortcuts for taking a screenshot of the entire screen, e.g., ShiftPrint. This should not hide the context menu.

I am not using the snap version of Firefox. I have a dedicated screen capture key (PrtSc), and it closes contextual menus when I type it.

@Lexible, are you stating you uninstalled the 22.04 Firefox, which is a Snap, and installed from Mozillla'a repository? https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Yup. That's what I am stating.

Refreshing my profile did the trick! (But whew! what a lot of work to reinstall all my add ons and reset my settings!)
